# Periods not shown when soft keyboard is open in landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to use a custom edittext to let a user enter an IP address. It only allows values up to 255 and 3 periods and it works fine in portrait but in landscape view with the soft keyboard displayed, only one of the periods is shown. The ip address is entered correctly in either orientation and once the keyboard is removed in landscape, the edittext displays the ip address correctly.

Any ideas? I would like the user to see the IP address as it is entered, not just when the keyboard is removed.

```
public class IPAddressKeyListener extends NumberKeyListener {

private char[] mAccepted;
private static IPAddressKeyListener sInstance;

@Override
protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
    return mAccepted;
}

private static final char[] CHARACTERS =
        new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.' };

private IPAddressKeyListener() {
    mAccepted = CHARACTERS;
}

public static IPAddressKeyListener getInstance() {
    if (sInstance != null) return sInstance;

    sInstance = new IPAddressKeyListener();
    return sInstance;
}

/**
 * Display a number-only soft keyboard.
 */
public int getInputType() {
    return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;
}

 public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, 
         int dstart,int dend) {

     if (end > start) {
         String destTxt = dest.toString();
         String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart)
                 + source.subSequence(start, end)
                 + destTxt.substring(dend);
         if (!resultingTxt.matches("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) {
            return "";
         } else {
             String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
             for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++) {
                 if (Integer.parseInt(splits[i]) > 255){
                     return "";
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 return null;
}
```

Test Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText edAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IPAddress);
    edAddress.setKeyListener(IPAddressKeyListener.getInstance());

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn.setText(edAddress.getText());
        }
    });     
}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/IPAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/IPAddress"
    android:layout_below="@+id/IPAddress"
    android:text="IPAddress" />
```